# scrollIntoView not creating sufficient padding

Tags: reactjs

I am working on the chat frontend for my app. When a new message appears, it doesn't scroll sufficiently to show the new question and the impending answers. I have to manually scroll to check for new messages.

Is there any way to fix this? If scrolling appears, it would be fine if the container automatically scrolls so that only the last question is visible and there is empty space below for the impending answer.

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react';
import InputComponent from './InputComponent';

function App({ theme }) {
  const [conversation, setConversation] = useState([]);
  const [question, setQuestion] = useState('');

  const conversationContainerRef = useRef(null);
  
    useEffect(() => {
    const conversationContainer = conversationContainerRef.current;
    if (conversationContainer) {
      conversationContainer.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'end', paddingBottom: '50px' });
    }
  }, [conversation]);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setQuestion(e.target.value);
  };

   const handleSubmit = () => {
let newElement = {};
setAsked("true");
newElement.question = question;

let array = [...conversation, newElement];
setConversation(array);
setQuestion("");
fetch(apiURL, {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    question: question,
  }),
}) 
 .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => {
    const lastIndex = array.length - 1;
    const lastItem = array[lastIndex];
    lastItem.answer = data.response;
    setConversation(array);
    setAsked("false");
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
  });
  };     

  return (
    <div style={{ height: '100vh', width: '100vw' }} className={`App ${theme}`}>
      <div ref={conversationContainerRef}>
        {conversation.length >= 1 &&
          conversation.map((item, index) => (
            <div key={index} style={{ marginBottom: '50px' }} className="conversation--container">
              <div className="chatblock user">{item.question}</div>
              {item.answer && <div className="chatblock">{item.answer} </div>}
            </div>
          ))}
      </div>

      <div className="bottom-div">
        <InputComponent value={question} handleChange={handleChange} handleSubmit={handleSubmit} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
.conversation--container {
  display: grid;
}

.chatblock {
  padding: 10px 15px 25px 20px;
}

.user {
  background: rgb(39, 39, 50)
}

.bottom-div {
  /* background-color: #19191d;  */
  /* background-color: red;  */
  background-color: #303042;
  width: 100vw;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100px;
}


.input--custom {
  outline: 0;
  background: #131316;
  border: 0px;
height: 90px;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  max-height: 140px;
  padding: 15px 40px 5px 15px;
  color: #ecebec;
  font-size: 16px;
  resize: vertical;
  overflow-y: scroll;

}


.App {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  /* align-items: center;
  justify-content: center; */
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  color: #333;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease, color 0.3s ease;
  outline: none;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen,
  Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.6rem;
}

.App.dark {
  background-color: #3e3e4a;
  color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using `scrollIntoView()` wrong. Check out [scrollintoview w3chools demo](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_element_scrollintoview).

So you need to specify the element to scroll to instead of the container. With the requirement is scroll to the newest message, in normally is scroll to the container's bottom, this trick is achieve it as well.

```
...
function App({ theme }) {
    const [conversation, setConversation] = useState([]);
    const [question, setQuestion] = useState("");

    const bottomConversationRef = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const bottomConversation = bottomConversationRef.current;
        if (bottomConversation) {
            bottomConversation.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth", block: "end", paddingBottom: "50px" });
        }
    }, [conversation]);

    ...

    return (
        <div
            style={{ height: "100vh", width: "100vw" }}
            className={`App ${theme}`}>
            <div>
                {conversation.length >= 1 &&
                    conversation.map((item, index) => (
                        ...
                    ))}
                <div ref={bottomConversationRef} className="bottom-holder"></div>
            </div>
            ...
        </div>
    );
}
```